# Splitting shapefile with counties into single boundary lines

Tags: qgis

I'm a beginning QGIS user and have a shapefile with polygons of all the county borders in Holland.

When I style this shapefile with a non-fill and a dashed line, all the adjacent (overlapping) lines are almost solid instead of dashed. This is because adjacent county borders are duplicates.

How do you get rid of those lines? tried to set the polygon shapes to lines and tried several geometry tools. Is this even possible? Or do you have to remove, clip all the double lines by hand?